# converting jquery(.each, .find,.next) to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm involved in converting the jquery codes to java script for a requirement.

Example 1 :

There are a few child elements with class name "child_elems" inside a parent html div with id "parent_elem". I need to change the width of the child elements dynamically. The jquery code will look like this:

```
 $(#parent_elem).find(.child_elems).each(function(){
    $(this).css("width","50px");
 });
```

Sample javascript:

```
var parentelem = document.getElementById("parent_elem");

var childelems = parentelem.getElementsByClassName("child_elems");

for(var i=0;i<childelems.length;i++)
   childelems[i].style.width = "50px";
```

This works but I m not sure whether this is an efficient way.

Can we do the same task without using for loop? Is there any equivalent for `.each` , `.next`, `.find` in javascript?

I'm very new to javascript and jquery as well, and would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a `for` loop? That's the natural choice to perform some action on a list of items. jQuery's `.each()` method is implemented using a `for` loop. jQuery is "just" a collection of functions written in JavaScript, so you can see how the functions you mentioned work if you look in the [jQuery.js file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js).

Comment: Why would you want to eliminate jQuery?

Comment: "Is there any equivalent for .each , .next, .find in javascript"? If there was a cross-browser equivalent why would jQuery team implement thir versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this if you must, jQuery is just a layer that sits on top of javascript. When you write jQuery, you're writing javascript.

If you really need to go down this route, it might be helpful to look at the jQuery source. James Padolsey made a really helpful tool for inspecting the various methods that jQuery provides. You can see the tool here: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.next.

Keep in mind that the jQuery team has spent **years** getting their code to work efficiently and for multiple browsers. Please don't be surprised if your code fails across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You may use below for your work, but beware they might not work with all browsers. It is always safe to use jQuery if possible.

```
// jQuery -> JavaScript
.each  -> array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
.find  -> document.querySelector(selectors), document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

Comment: Always sure . but better performance- not always sure :) 
I used to think the same way like you and then I saw this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLISnANteJY

Fantastic insight and a must watch for javascript developers

Answer (score 0):

You could start looking at these functions code at github.
.find = https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L13
.each = https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L541